# Run pylint daily and show results in webpage

Tags: python, pylint

Is there any project (preferably open source) that can run pylint daily on all my source code and and show some kind of report that aggregates the scores so that I can see which files are doing good and which are not. I would like to show how the code quality is trending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely try jenkins CI with [violations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) plugin.

And, FYI, there is a nice and useful service for github projects: https://codeq.io